# Redux-logger does not work with(with react-native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Now I'm configuring project using react-native+expo, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-logger. Everything was installed and expo builds project. But when I run web-version I dont see logs.

StoreCOnfig:

```
import {
    createStore,
    applyMiddleware,
    compose
}                     from 'redux';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';
import thunk          from 'redux-thunk';

//main, combined reducer
import reducer        from '../reducers/reducer';

const initialState = {};
const logger = createLogger({
    timestamp : true,
    diff : false,
});
const middleware = [thunk, logger];
const storeConfig = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
);

export default storeConfig;
```

MainComponent with redux-connect:

```
import React       from 'react';
//redux
import {Provider}  from 'react-redux';
import store       from './src/coreModules/storeConfig';
//components
import {
  StyleSheet,
}                  from 'react-native';
import MainScreen  from "./src/containers/screens/main/MainScreen";


export default function App () {
 return (
 <Provider store={store}>
 <MainScreen/>
 </Provider>
 );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#b8b8b8',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Avoid to use this logger it causes lots of issues, like performance. Use react-native debugger for logging redux.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar maybe, but for my purposes it was suitable instrument to work with simple react.